# Download process (start/pause/resume) with multi threading in android

Tags: android, multithreading, download

I have task for creating downloading process like browser.
on clicking downloadable link have to start download in background (which can be possible with service or other Libraries) with showing progressive notification. on other side I have to show all the background downloading process in downloading screen with individual progress.

I have tried with service, in that the same service will call for multiple file download. but in that how to pause/resume single download?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to manage state of each downloading in That Foreground Service. Or You can use easy way i.e `DownloadManager`.

Comment: @ADM I have created one service for the downloading from download will be start. at a time I have started 3 download with the same service from that I have to pause 2nd download is it possible to stop the 2nd download?

Comment: Possible Yes .. But you need to code for it cause you will create a seperate thread for each download ..Apart from that `DownloadManager` doeas exactly the same if you can use it ..

Comment: @ADM without download manager how can do it?
I have tried like this 
Intent intent = new Intent( this, DownloadService2.class );
intent.putExtra( DownloadService.FILENAME, "FILENAME" );
intent.putExtra( DownloadService.URL,"FILE URL" );
startService( intent ); 

in service there is code for write data to Outpustream.

If you have any suggestion link please share it. will be more helpful.

Comment: You can just google `download multiple files in service android` .. Its quite broad to answer this question . If you are looking for idea behind it checkout the links in search .